# Practically - what are the changes that SO talent will be seeing?

Tags: discussion, blog, stack-overflow-talent

There was a recent [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/07/an-update-on-our-product-led-saas-transformation/) from Prasanth that talked about planned changes in Stack Overflow Careers. It seems to be an extremely high-level overview that *something* is changing, and both as a fairly visible advocate for at least the public Q&A (work has all sorts of fun that make teams an impossibility), and due to the fact that to some extent the success of the revenue-generating products affects the availability of resources, it might be nice to know what these things mean.

> We are realigning the Talent business to focus more on customer employer branding and company awareness needs and moving away from job slots and direct hiring.

I understand that this could mean SO Talent's moving away from being a jobs board. I personally see this as a positive change - since having a key part of the organisation in an *extremely* competitive field, outside its core business is risky, but... what is talent going to be going forward *exactly*?

> This will tie the product closer to what we offer through Stack Overflow Advertising and is part of what we’re calling our “Reach and Relevance” strategy, allowing companies to reach and share relevant information with millions of developers and technologists.

Might need some explanation for us non-marketing types ;)

> These changes, however, impacted a small portion of employees within our Sales & Customer Success organization.

Ugh, never a good thing to hear. Was this part of the covid related restructuring or was there a second round - would there be a re-assignment of these folks elsewhere in the business unit or other units?

Comment: I think the big question is whether job ads are going away or not. And if they are intended to stay, whether they'll be useful at all if the company doesn't actually focus on that part.

Comment: Thanks for asking this much more politely than I was going to :) I was going to go for "What does the most recent blogpost actually mean, when translated from Silicon Valley CEO-speak into English", or something like that...

Comment: For all my sins, amongst other things, I'm one of my majors was in management- I understand *some* of this as a second language. I think my main points of confusion are - there's quite a lot of knowledge of SE's strategy and broader plans that's needed to make sense of this, and some of it is *marketing*, which I have no background in ;) .

Comment: Maybe something like LinkedIn for programmers. But I guess as so often, the answer is that nobody knows for sure until it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful question about this. We're discussing internally and we'll be getting an answer out to y'all in the next week to give you some more info about this change.

Comment: @Catija now approaching 6-8 weeks

Comment: @Catija Are you still planning on answering this?

Comment: @Catija I would also like to hear an answer on this

Comment: [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) seems to cover some of it, and I'm popping a link for reference pending a fuller answer